# Finding unique values of column depending on unique values of another column

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have a table as under:

```
**A**         **B** 
2018-01-25    Red
2018-01-25    Black
2018-01-25    Black
2018-01-24    Blue
2018-01-24    Blue
2018-01-24    Red
```

Now I want to display unique values of B based on unique values of A. 
I expect column C and D to be like:

```
**C  D**
2018-01-25  Red
2018-01-25  Black
2018-01-24  Blue
2018-01-24  Red
```

Please help me to write VBA script in Excel macro to solve this case. I have used the formula: `"=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:A2=A2)*($B$2:B2=B2))>1,0,1)"` but it takes almost 15-20 min to calculate for 50k records.

I want to use specifically xls format, can't use xlsm or xlsx which provide distinct count in pivot table.

Comment: why don't you use the "Remove Duplicates" feature of Excel? No need for VBA then.

Comment: I can't use, i have to use this file for automation.

Comment: you can automate this feature too: `Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo` removes all duplicates from columns A:B

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Remove Duplicates* feature of Excel

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyAndRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'specify your sheet name

    ws.Range("A:B").Copy ws.Range("C:D") 'copy colums A:B to C:D
    ws.Range("C:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
       'remove duplicates from C:D
End Sub
```

Don't forget to change `Header:=xlNo` to `Header:=xlYes` if there is a header in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what @Peh said - here would be your code:

```
Columns("A:B").Copy
Columns("C:C").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$D$" & ActiveSheet.Range("D" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: You should follow a good practice if you post code. Always reference a sheet for columns and ranges etc. Avoid using `.Select`, `ActiveSheet` etc.